# Looking for two sides in a right triangle where the perimeter is known

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

The perimeter in a right triangle is known and also one side.
Am I right thinking that the hypotenuse and the other side can only have one set of lengths?

Using Geogebra I was able to approximate the lengths but I wonder if someone can help me find a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Let $b$ be the known side, being $a$ the other side and $c$ the hypotenuse. Let $p$ be the perimeter. Then $a$ and $c$ are thee solution of the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}a+c=p-b\\c^2-a^2=b^2.\end{array}\right.$$This solution is$$a=\frac{p(p-2b)}{2(p-b)}\text{ and }c=\frac{2b^2-2bp+p^2}{2(p-b)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $c$ be the length of the hypothenuse and let $a$ and $b$ be the lengths of the legs. Assume that we know the value of $b$ and the perimeter $P$. Then the perimeter is given by
$$ P = a+b+c, $$
and by Pythagoras, we know that
$$ c^2 = a^2+b^2, $$
so
$$ P = a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad P-a-b = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}. $$
Squaring both sides, we obtain
$$ P^2+a^2+b^2-2Pa-2Pb+2ab = a^2+b^2  \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad a = \frac{2Pb-P^2}{2b-2P} = \frac{P}{2}\frac{2b-P}{b-P}. $$
You can find $c$ by using Pythagoras.